# How do 240 GiB fill up a 1 TB drive?

Tags: linux, ssd, storage, luks

I just got the message that:

```
Fehler: Partition / ist überfüllt: 6009 Blöcke werden benötigt, 0 Blöcke sind frei
Fehler: Konnte den Vorgang nicht durchführen (Nicht genug freier Festplattenspeicher)
Fehler sind aufgetreten, keine Pakete wurden aktualisiert.
```

(Partition / is more than full)

while I still *SHOULD* have free space available. My disks are LUKS-encrypted and auto-unlocked at boot, if that's of relevance.

what completely puzzles me is the following:

```
root@Arschlinux ~# df -h
Dateisystem           Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
devtmpfs                16G       0   16G    0% /dev
tmpfs                   16G    213M   16G    2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   16G    1,4M   16G    1% /run
tmpfs                   16G       0   16G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cryptroot  954G    238G     0  100% /
tmpfs                   16G     13M   16G    1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p1         500M    319M  181M   64% /boot
/dev/mapper/backup     458G     27G  408G    7% /backup
/dev/mapper/home       916G    539G  331G   62% /home
tmpfs                  3,2G     16K  3,2G    1% /run/user/1405
```

cryptroot is the relevant entry: 954 GB in size, filled with 238 GB of data and nothing left.

What could be a reason for that? especially after i scanned my disk with ncdu root should be way smaller.

[ncdu output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAoLS.png)

**EDIT**

```
$ df -ih
Dateisystem           Inodes IBenutzt IFrei IUse% Eingehängt auf
devtmpfs                3,9M      506  3,9M    1% /dev
tmpfs                   3,9M      303  3,9M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   3,9M      914  3,9M    1% /run
tmpfs                   3,9M       18  3,9M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cryptroot      0        0     0     - /
tmpfs                   3,9M       40  3,9M    1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p1             0        0     0     - /boot
/dev/mapper/home         59M     664K   58M    2% /home
/dev/mapper/backup       30M     768K   29M    3% /backup
tmpfs                   3,9M       29  3,9M    1% /run/user/1405
```

EDIT 2

```
root@Arschlinux ~# btrfs fi show /
Label: 'Bootdrive'  uuid: 9225ac48-071e-4f35-8e0b-a1bf256aecdf
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 237.14GiB
    devid    1 size 953.36GiB used 239.02GiB path /dev/mapper/cryptroot
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `df -ih`. You’re most likely running out of inodes. // Also, what filesystem are you using?

Comment: added the output, the Filesystem is BTRFS.

Comment: If it’s btrfs, you need to use btrfs tools to check space usage. Especially of snapshots and volumes.

Comment: I did and it pretty much confirms what df sais.

Comment: [Ubuntu thinks Btrfs disk is full but it's not](https://askubuntu.com/q/464074/253474), [BTRFS: “no space left on device”, but btrfs command says otherwise](https://serverfault.com/q/790464/343888), [BTRFS, out of space, but there is plenty of space](https://serverfault.com/q/942996/343888)